# Response Code: 404 when running Jmeter Test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I want to performance testing using Jmeter.
Example url: "http://localhost:4200/xxx/yyy/zzz"
And I use:

- server name or ip: localhost
- port: 4200
- path: /xxx/yyy/zzz

As a result Jmeter given Error 404 : Not Found

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

As per [404 Not Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) status code documentation:

> The HTTP `404 Not Found` response status code indicates that the **server cannot find the requested resource**. Links that lead to a 404 page are often called broken or dead links and can be subject to [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

So double check your Path and make sure that the relevant resource exists on your server.

If you don't experience the error in the browser I would recommend recording your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium).